# How to search for exact date match in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a couple of items in my ES database with fields containing 2020-02-26T05:24:55.757Z for example. Is it possible to (with the URI Search, _search?q=...) search for exact dates? For example, in this case, I would like to find items from 2020-02-26. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. You could refer to query string [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges) for more info.

```
curl localhost:9200/your_index_name/_search?q=your_date_field:%7B2020-02-26%20TO%20*%7D
```

You would need to **encode** the url. query part looks like `q=your_date_field:{2020-02-26 TO *}`

Above query in REST api would look like

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "your_date_field": {
        "gte": "2020-02-26"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For `exact` dates following would work

```
curl localhost:9200/your_index_name/_search?q=your_date_field:2020-02-26
```

Comment: Note that he's looking for the exact date `2020-02-26`, not dates bigger than `2020-02-26`

Comment: @Val, in question he has written  **from 2020-02-26**, so I thought he wants everything from that particular date

Comment: I was focused on "search for exact dates", we'll see what he says :-)

Comment: Haha, -1 on me for such a bad example date... yes, lets say 1978-01-10 the exact date for that then. Not greater than or less than, just that exact date.

Comment: I have edited the answer, let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old, I came across it, so maybe others will do so too.

If you want to only work in UTC, you can use a `match` query, like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "your_date_field": {
        "query": "2020-02-26"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to consider things matching on a particular date in a different timezone, you have to use a `range` query, like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "your_date_field": {
        "gte": "2020-02-26",
        "lte": "2020-02-26",
        "time_zone": "-08:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```