# Elasticsearch Query: Retrieve id Groups with Only 'Open' Status

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with Elasticsearch and trying to construct a query that retrieves specific groups of documents based on the id field. Each group should consist only of documents with the status 'Open' and a label containing the substring "X1" Here's a simplified representation of the data:

```
id, status, label, date
1, CLOSED, X1, 07/02/2024
1, OPEN, X1, 07/02/2024
2, OPEN, X1, 07/02/2024
2, OPEN, X1, 05/02/2024
3, OPEN, X1, 07/02/2024
1, OPEN, X2, 07/02/2024
```

for example in this case I want it to return the lines with value:

```
2, OPEN, X1, 07/02/2024
```

how can I achieve this ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: why you return only `2, OPEN, X1, 07/02/2024` and not `2, OPEN, X1, 05/02/2024`

Comment: because I want to sort the result by the most recent element.

Answer (score 0):

A bool/must query like below should give you the results by id (assuming id has integer mapping), status and label.

```
{
    "_source": [],
    "size": 10,
    "min_score": 0.5,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "id": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "status": "OPEN"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "label": "X1"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [],
            "should": [],
            "must_not": []
        }
    }
}
```

But if you also want to check the date you may need to look at this link
[How to search for exact date match in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729456/how-to-search-for-exact-date-match-in-elasticsearch)